# How to choose ideal K when multiple K share same testing accuracy in KNN

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, classification, knn

For my KNN classifier, I plotted the training and testing accuracy for different values of `K` (# nearest neighbours) as follows:

[image]

As you can see that the `K`s in range [1, 5] share the same testing accuracy.

In such a case, what value of `K` should be selected for inference?

**What I tried?**

In this case the elbow technique cannot be applied.

**PS:**
I used the following function to split my training and testing data:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=.3, random_state=4, shuffle=True, stratify=y)
```

Comment: K=1 I guess since it's less expensive, but it sure looks like you're over-fitting.

Comment: Is this "about programming or software development"? That is, how does this fit on StackOverflow?

Answer (score 0):

By making a decision, you basically extend the kNN model in some way.
This can have a wide range of consequences and the best decision depends on your actual problem and might not be straightforward.

That being said, the following approaches come to my mind immediately:

1. Select the lowest `k`. This is the most efficient to compute.
2. Select the highest `k`. This degrades the effect of 'noisy' samples and would serve as some kind of regularization.
3. Increase the number of test samples such that you get more accurate (and probably different) accuracies.